# Boost Rtree C2228 error

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to create a ranged tree using boost library, Here is my code:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;
typedef bg::model::point<float, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;

typedef bg::model::box<point> box;
typedef std::pair<box, unsigned> value;

// create the rtree using default constructor
int main(){
    bgi::rtree< value, bgi::linear<16> > rtree;
return 0;
}
```

But I get this error:

> Error 1   error C2228: left of '.select_on_container_copy_construction' must have class/struct/union
>   I am using boost version 1_55_0 and visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem. This is a known problem with VS 2013 and Boost 1.55, check out the [bug report here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9332). You just need to upgrade to a later version of Boost.